# Consolidate multiple column values into single row

Tags: plsql

I have data in this format in a single table:

Key      Col1   Col2   Col3Type 
Part1    abc1   cde1               X   
Part1                            fgh1     Y

I want the result of my select query to consolidate all column values for Part1 like this:

Key      Col1   Col2   Col3
Part1    abc1   cde1   fgh1

I tried using GROUP BY/HAVING and doing just a self join using the value of the Type column.
These didnt work.

```
    select 
    a.Key ,a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col3
    from table a 
    join table b on 
    a.Key = b.Key and 
    b.Type ='Y' and 
    a.Type= 'X'
```

Basically the constraint I noticed is that if I have the group by / having, I only get the rows for which all three column values are present. Also I dont know how to get the column values in the outlet sql. Select a.* will give me from first row. How do I get b.?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  Key,
  max(Col1) as Col1,
  max(Col2) as Col2,
  max(Col3) as Col3
from table
group by Key
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you Egor. I am off to read up about max.